# Problems with Angular and Firebase: auth and User

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am doing a project in Angular with Firebase. In the auth.service.ts file when importing auth and User, Visual Studio Code does not recognize them.

```
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { User } from 'firebase';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public user:User;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  async login( email:string, password:string){}
  register(){}
  logout(){}
  getCurrentUser(){}

}
```

I have the problem in:

import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

import { User } from 'firebase';

Please, help.

I have this erros:
This: 'auth' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) Module '"../../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. Did you mean to use 'import auth from "../../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?ts(2614). –

And this: import User Module '"../../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'User'. Did you mean to use 'import User from "../../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?ts(2614) –

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: This: 'auth' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Module '"../../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. Did you mean to use 'import auth from "../../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?ts(2614).

Comment: And this: import User
Module '"../../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'User'. Did you mean to use 'import User from "../../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?ts(2614)

Answer (score 2):

`AngularFireAuth` is a wrapper class, so you don't need `auth`. As the error says the `firebase` package has no exported member called `User` or `auth`.. You can check the docs on how to use [`AngularFireAuth`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
      <h1>Hello {{ user.displayName }}!</h1>
      <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <ng-template #showLogin>
      <p>Please login.</p>
      <button (click)="login()">Login with Google</button>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```